# CMD test database connection

Tags: database, windows, cmd

I setup a site on my localhost and I am getting unable to connect to database errors. (its not my local database) and now I am trying to connect to that database in the command line to see if its a firewall issue or php issue.

Whats the command to test a database connection (not local) in cmd?

Answer (score 20):

Here is a quick way you can test for database connectivity with no other database software installed :

1. Create a new text file anywhere on the computer
2. Rename the file and make the extentsion .udl (*TestConnection.udl*)
3. When prompted about changing the extension select "Yes"
4. Double click the file and Boom! Instant database connection tool

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what kind of database are you trying to connect to.

e.g. if you're connecting to Oracle db you may use something like this:

```
sqlplus <user>/<password>@<service>
```

if it's a Microsoft SQL Server you may use

```
osql -U<user> -P<password> -S<instance>
```

If you just want to test network ports to be sure no firewall is preventing connection, you can use telnet tool,

```
telnet <server-address> <service-port>
```

(default tcp port for Oracle db service is 1521, for SQL Server's 1433)

Answer (score 0):

It depends very much on which database you want to connect to. MySQL? Oracle? PostgreSQL? SQL Servrer? DB2? Filemaker? Informix? One thing you could try is opening an [ADO connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681519) with VBScript:

```
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "..."
WScript.Echo conn.State
conn.Close
```

Replace `"..."` with a [connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) matching your database.